# Cómo puedo eliminar un objeto de una base de datos con flask

Tags: python, base-de-datos, flask

```html
<h2>Todos los usuarios</h2>
<ul>
  {% for i in lista_usuarios %}
    <span >{{i}}</span>
         <a href='/borrar/{{i.nid}}'>Borrar</a>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

```py
@app.route('/borrar/<nid>')
def borrar_usuario(nid):
   conexion_borrar = sqlite3.connect('usuarios.db')
   cursor_borrar = conexion_borrar.cursor()

   numer_id = int(nid)

   cursor_borrar.execute('DELETE FROM contactos WHERE nid=?',numer_id)
   cursor_borrar.commit()
   conexion_borrar.close()
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Porque el titulo esta en ingles? que pasa con ese codigo? usa el boton [edit] y arregla todo por favor